# How to include "[" and "]" in awk pattern search

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have following code in a bash script

```
stat_pattern="POSITION_UPDATE [ For INRecord ]"
cat my_file.txt | awk -v pattern="$stat_pattern" '$0 ~ pattern' | tail -n 1
```

but it does not return any output. 
I tried "\" also with "[". buy it did not help also.

Please tell me how to treat "[" "]" characters as a part of search string...

Comment: UUOC, `awk` can read the file directly - you can skip the `cat` there.

Comment: Post small content of my_file.txt

Comment: you could have just done `fgrep "$stat_pattern"` instead of awk there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember tilde operator `~` in awk treats matching string as a **Regular Expression** and if you have special regex characters (`[` and `]` in your case) then regex matching will fail. For your case its better to use an [**awk function index(in, find)**](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) to find a string inside another string like this code:

```
awk -v pattern="$stat_pattern" 'index($0, pattern) {line=$0} 
       END{print line}' my_file.txt
```

Also note that you has unnecessary cat and tail piped in to your command. All that can be done in awk itself therefore I refactored your commands.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava!!! I tried your instructions and they worked. Thanks Janos, Adrian and Parkydr for replying to my question. Really appreciate your help....

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the escape character, like this:

```
stat_pattern='POSITION_UPDATE \\[ For INRecord \\]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the '[' and the '\' so it should be

```
stat_pattern="POSITION_UPDATE \\\[ For INRecord \\\]"
```